# Get type of a field of class

Tags: c#, class, generics, reflection

I have classes like this:

```
class A
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}
class B
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}
class C
{
    public A a;
    public B b;
}

public class Test<T> where T : class, new()
{
     public Test()
     {
        FieldInfo[] x = typeof(T).GetFields().ToArray();
        Type y = x[0].GetType();
     }
}
```

When I declare `Test<C> c = new T`
`typeof(T).GetFields().ToArray()` Returns the two fields `a of type A` and `b of type B` as expected. but when I want to get type of first field itself, like this:
`Type y = x[0].GetType();`, the value of y is `System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo` and not `A`

Why is it so? I need to get to the class `A` so that I can get its fields and ...

Comment: `x` is an array of `FieldInfo`, and `x[0]` is a `FieldInfo` (or an implementation of...), what did you expect to get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`FieldType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.fieldtype) on the returned [`FieldInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo) for that.

`GetType()` returns the type of *current* object, which is `FieldInfo`, and not the type that it describes.

`FieldInfo`is a class that describes a field and it's type; and the type information *for the field it describes* is stored in `FieldInfo`.

Comment: Well I got that but I see `FieldType` on runtime when I put a break point but when in my code I use it like: `y = x[0].FieldType;` I get an error: `'MemberInfo' does not contain a definition for 'FieldType' and no extension method 'FieldType' accepting a first argument of type 'MemberInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`